# Advanced paging, sorting and filtering in REST API design

Tags: rest

In REST API, it is considered a good practice to handle sorting, filtering and pagination of collections using URI query parameters, like:

```
GET /employees?offset=30&limit=15&name=Mary&sort=-surname
```

Unfortunately, in some "advanced" cases, the number of parameters may "explode", so that this solution is not possible any more.

Back to the previous example, suppose that we want to apply some more sophisticated filters on many other fields (eg.: address contains "NY", age > 30, age <= 40, (marital status is "married" AND salary<100000USD) OR (marital status is "divorced" AND salary>=100000USD), and many other... ).

Clearly, in such a case, a simple set of query parameters is not suitable.

How such a situation should be designed? Maybe the client should send a POST containing some structured data representing the query? Is there any more-or-less standard agreement on how to design such queries?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you defined "advanced" cases? Generally, you should be able to quantify parameters, so the number of parameters doesn't "explode".

Comment: Combining clauses with boolean operators (as in the example) may lead to a very large filter. Another basic example that requires a lot of data in the query could be the "in" operator, like: name is in ("Mary", "Jhon", "Carl", ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is to make search filters a REST resource meaning creating new REST methods:

- POST `/filters`, expecting a body with filters, e.g. `(marital status is "married" AND salary<100000USD) OR (marital status is "divorced" AND salary>=100000USD)` and returning the unique id of this search, and (to avoid a roundtrip to the server) the first results, and links to the next results
- GET `/filters/<id>/<offset>`, returning the results for search `id` starting from `offset`

Comment: Great! This translates the filtering of a collection into the creation of a filter. I like it because the POST verb is effectively used to create a new resource (a filter!), then the GET verb is subsequently used to get its properties (the result of the filter). Seems OK!

Comment: Yes, exactly. Filters become first class citizens of your app. Your app can use them to e.g. present to the user "your last searches".

Comment: the problem with that is difficult implementation and expensive usage. You essentially need a custom parser for this. Its called RQL. I am not sure why it hasnt found much adoption. Maybe because youre are so close to writing sql. I am not sure if its good to go too close to something like sql with your query langauge. At some point you are better of using sql directly or some other query langauge, like mongo query format. Problem with that is again, santizing the users queries and mapping to parameterzied queries against a database.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried posting a body with filters?

```
{
  "age": {
    "$gte": 30,
    "$lte": 40
  },
  "status": {
    "$in": [
        "Divorced",
        "Single"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the solution I was thinking at, but I don't like it because we are using a POST, while we should semantically use a GET. I'd prefer something that does not diverge too much from the usual REST "good practices"...

Comment: This solution is OK, if combined with the one suggested by @Adam, http://stackoverflow.com/a/42893377/1288109 : the idea is to use a POST not on the resource itself, but to create a new "filter" entity. POST /employees/filter